# (How) Can CPE Bach's *Solfeggietto* (Solfeggio) in C Minor be played left-hand alone?

Tags: piano, technique, fingering, keyboard, arranging

In researching [CPE Bach - Solfeggietto - cross-hand playing style?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106884/piano-cpe-bach-solfegietto-cross-hand-playing-style), I stumbled on the following statement in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfeggietto):

> The work is often performed by left-hand alone.

#### How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of the piece is straightforward, and the fingering reasonably intuitive. However, there are some sections to watch out for and some requiring license.

## mm. 3-4

These two measures require some wide leaps so may need extra practice for accuracy.

## mm. 13, 15, and 25

The problem in these three measures is that the hand-span is too large (for anyone who can't reach  a minor seventeenth -- 2 octaves + minor 3rd). There are a few options:

1. Treat the notated left-hand notes as grace notes.
2. Roll the chords.
3. Change octaves.

Here is an illustration of m. 13 and it's options. Measures 15 and 25 are similar.

[image: m13 LH alone options]

## mm. 14, 16, and 26-29

These passages require careful fingering and then practice for accuracy. Fortunately, the chords are staccato; otherwise, the leaps to the high notes would be prohibitive for many of us.

Here's one possibility for m. 14.

[image: m14 LH alone fingering]

## mm. 22-24

In these measures, a whole-note is given in the left hand. To accommodate, either use some judicious pedal, or cut the note short -- two beats will be sufficient to communicate the intended effect.